# C++ constructor automatic variable assign

Tags: c++, variables, assign

Let's say I have the class:

```
class foobar {
public:
    foobar(int _x, int _y) {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }
    int x, y;
};
```

Is there any way to assign x and y to the values passed to foobar(int, int) instead of assigning them myself?

[Answer]
Initialization Lists is what I need to use (Thanks all for clarifying)

I can write the code as such:

```
class foobar {
public:
    foobar(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    int x, y;
};
```

That means I don't have to underscore my input arguments either x(x) will work as intended

Comment: is there a reason why you dont want to assign them values

Comment: What do you mean assign the values instead of assigning them? And are you sure you have the assignment direction right? Your question implies you want to overwrite the input variables.

Comment: Thank you all for your input, turns out Kerreck and Pierre were exactly right and what I want to use is called "Initialization List". Thanks!

Comment: One important terminology issue: assignment is not the same as initialization. In your first example, you have assignments (**to** `x` and `y`). The initialization methods in the answers do not perform assignment, but rather initialization. You can only initialize something once, you can assign **to** it many times.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [*member-initialization-list*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). It is still your job but it is a better practice:

```
foobar(int _x, int _y): x(_x), y(_y) {
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

---

If you really don't want to assign those values you can initialize those members with a class with no constructors ([**aggregate class**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_classes#Aggregate_classes)):

```
class foo
{
public:
    int x, y;
};
foo{1, 2}; // <= Braces initialization
```

Working example: http://ideone.com/NlbkKb.

Answer (score 3):

If your class is an aggregate, you can initialize it with the brace syntax:

```
class foobar
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
};

foobar f { 1, 2 };
```

Otherwise, you should initialize the elements in the constructor:

```
class foobar
{
public:
    foobar(int x_, int y_) : x(x_), y(y_)  {  }
private:
    int x;
    int y;
};

foobar f(1, 2);
```

(You can also use the brace syntax in the second case.)

Comment: So, it seems there is no option to explicitly "introduce" the aggregate initialization to a non-aggregate class. Something like: `foobar({}) = default;` (my own imaginary syntax)